# Unity WebGL build throws errors

Tags: socket.io, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

[image]

I am working on a multiplayer game for WebGL platform and i am using (http://lockstep.io/ - SocketIo & node.js server ) for handling the game.

I am facing these issues as shown in the attached image.

I have no idea about what these errors state?

I don't think that the issue is from my coding side as my multiplayer game runs perfectly in standalone builds with more than 4 instances of the standalone build.

But it does not even open in my WebGL build.

Does WebGL does not support threading??

Please guide. What are these errors all about? Can these issues be solved?? or Do i have to change my whole project implementation?

Comment: Would be nice to go back to all your questions and accept those answers you said "thank you" or the answers that solved your problems. There are many of them. If you don't people wont answer your questions.

Comment: I did not get what you are trying to say.
Was i rude?
Sorry if i did something wrong.
Thank You for commenting

Answer (score 2):

Unity WebGl does not support Multithreading. Although Unity is working hard to bring Thread support in WebGL.

Do not compare standalone with WebGL because many features are not supported in WebGL. Looking at the error, it says something about Thread and that could definitely be the problem. About 90% chances it is the problem.

You cannot solve this problem right now unless you remove the use of **SocketIo**.

I don't know how **SocketIo** is implemented so I can't tell you if Thread is the only problem it has but if it uses other API's **not** supported in WebGL, then you will still have problems.

The only known network API that is made and optimized to work with WebGL is the new Unity web API called [UnityWebRequest](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html). You have to modify your code to use that. The link I provided provides many examples needed to get started with it.

if you use anything like webrequestm System.web or socket, WebGL will crash. [UnityWebRequest](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html) is the only solution. It is faster than WWW and you need **Unity 5.2** and above to use it.

Comment: Thank you.
I will look into UnityWebRequest

I don't know whether i will be able to modify the socket io code.
Let's see.

Comment: That's the only option.To use something else other than SocketIo until they fix their API. SocketIo does not even mention WebGl support on their website, so that is a big sign that it doesn't work with WebGL.

Comment: I am facing the same issue...Can you suggest how to replace socket object via UnityWebRequest.

Comment: @vikky The link I provided about UnityWebRequest has many many examples. Just scroll down on that page and you will see many examples.

Comment: @Programmer actually I have a code of https://github.com/vovacooper/Unity3d_MQTT. this code use system.net.socket object , which create issue in WebGl....Now my task  to change the code ,So that it would be perfect run on WebGl.So my Idea is to change the object socket from UnityWebRequest will solve the issue.....

Comment: @vikky That will be hard to port. You need a team of people to do that or it will take you about a week to do it yourself. It's not something that can be answered here.

Comment: @Programmer....Suppose If I store the (mqtt massege)data in database and want to read that data from our WebGl...Any Idea ....Please suggest

Comment: If all you want to do is read data from database, then you don't even need that thing from that link you posted. You need to learn php or c++. You sound like a beginner so I suggest you go with php because it is easy. You do a post request from unity using the UnityWebRequest to your server. Then php code in your server will pull the requested info from the database return the result to unity.